# IE : Middle click on link with click onlick listener will sometime open the link, sometimes trigger the listener

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, mouseclick-event

On Internet Explorer 11 (not reproduiced on Chrome 69 & Firefox 61),

I have a `a href` link with a `$.click` registered.

Referring to my code below, using the mouse middle-click,

- `[dossier-link]` opens in a new tab  <= expected behaviour
- `[action-link]` calls the function  <= unexpected behaviour

My code :

```
$('[action-link]').each(function () {
    var id = parseInt($(this).attr('action-link'));
    $(this).click((e) => {
        if (e.button == 1 || e.which == 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
            afficherTimeline(id, TimelineType.Action);
        }
    });
});
$('[dossier-link]').each(function () {
    var id = parseInt($(this).attr('dossier-link'));
    $(this).click((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        afficherTimeline(id, TimelineType.Dossier)
    });
});
```

and the corresponding html

```
<tr class="action">
   <td class="dossier nostretch">
      <a href="/Demandes/44012" dossier-link="44012">#627</a>
   </td>
   <td class="nostretch">
      <a href="/Demandes/44012" dossier-link="44012"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: With your reputation, you should know that asking for help about problems in your code should include a [mcve], right? It would help a lot the people who are here trying to help you. Thanks

Comment: You're definitely right.